# Java: how to specity a type for a function parameter without specifying a full type

Tags: java

Suppose i have a interface like this,

```
interface MyIntf{
  void generate();
}
```

and a method like below

```
void run(Myintf x) {
  x.generate();
}
```

I could call run() with an object of a class which implements MyIntf.

but is it possible in Java to declare run without an explicit name for the interface.

i.e. can i specify run() like this?

```
void run("Some object which has a method called 'void generate()'" x){
  x.generate();
}
```

and run() can be called with an object of any class which has a method called

```
void generate();
```

Comment: It isn't, you always need to define the type.

Comment: Why do you want to take this approach ?. Just curious.

Comment: so there is no way to declare an anonymous type with minimal information that i want

Comment: @SajanChandran just want to decouple a parts of a program. if i use an interface, i get some decoupling, but is it possible to go even further. i.e. specify the interface anonymously, without a name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses ["nominative"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system) rather than ["structural"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) typing.

Just because a method has the same name and parameters, doesn't mean it does the same thing (put the camera/gun to you head and shoot). If you need to make a legacy type conform to a particular interface, use an adapter. Avoid reflection.

Answer (score 4):

You must then use reflection to do what you want. Something like:

```
void run(Object o) {
    Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("generate", new Class[0]);
    if (m!=null)
        m.invoke(o, new Object[0]);
}
```

You must also add the necessary try/catch (which I don't know by heart), and I think you can pass `null` instead of the empty arrays.

Comment: It is surely possible to do it by reflection, But I want the parameter specification of run() to capture this information : any object which has a method void generate() so that i dont need to use reflection.

Comment: Then sorry, no solution for that. Either you force the type, either you use an instanceof, but in all cases, your argument will need to declare that it implements your interface.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that. This is exactly what interfaces are for :)
Unless you don't use reflection..

Answer (score 0):

You mean as if you would do something like this?:

```
void run(Object x) {
  ((Myintf)x).generate();
}
```

Comment: I dont want the implementation of run() to know any interface names. run() only cares that the object has a method called generate()

Comment: In that case you have to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
void run(Object x){
    try{
        //use reflection to try and run a generate() method on x
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

but there's no way to enforce that at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to specify "some object which has a method called `void generate()`" in Java in the way that you have in mind.

In principle you could do this with reflection: you just pass in an `Object` and at runtime you check if there is a `void generate()` method that you can call. This means however that you are throwing away the type safety that the compiler provides; I don't recommend using this solution.

```
public void run(Object obj) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("generate");
    m.invoke(obj);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do this in Java is to either use reflection or use the instanceof operator (which isn't recommended) and then cast the object being passed in to the correct class/interface.